# ASP.NET MVC and AngularJS cannot refresh DIV

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I made Single application page using mvc controller and web api2 controller and angularJS.
I have to create table of events and to show for unregistered users all event list in table (ng-repeat), but for registered users, to show additional option (register / unregister for event...etc...), means to render additional table column.

in .cshtml I use :

```
<div id="EventsList" ng-show="EventsList" class=table-responsive>
    <h4><b>Event List</b><font color="red" size="2"><i> --- Only logged in users can register for EVents ...</i></font></h4>

    <span ng-click="AddEvent()" class="btnAdd"> - Add NEW Event - </span><br />

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Id</b></td>
            <td><b>Genre</b></td>
            <td><b>City</b></td>
            <td><b>ArtistName</b></td>
            <td><b>Date</b></td>
            <td><b>Time</b></td>
            @if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Level"] == "1" || HttpContext.Current.Session["Level"] == "0")
            {
                <td><b>Action</b></td>
            }
            @if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Level"] == "1")
            {
                <td><b>Admin action</b></td>
            }
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="eventsdata in eventstable">
            <td>
                <b>{{eventsdata.Id}}</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{eventsdata.Genre}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{eventsdata.City}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{eventsdata.ArtistName}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{eventsdata.Date}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{eventsdata.Time}}
            </td>
            @if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Level"] == "1" || HttpContext.Current.Session["Level"] == "0")
            {
                <td>
                    <span ng-click="AttendEvent()" class="btnRed">Attend this event</span>
                    <span ng-click="UnattendEvent()" class="btnRed">Unattend this Event</span>
                </td>
            }
            @if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Level"] == "1")
            {
                <td>
                    <span ng-click="DeleteEvent()" class="btnRed">Delete Event</span>
                    <span ng-click="UpdateEvent()" class="btnRed">Update Event</span>
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <hr>
    <br />
</div>
```

Everyting is ok before login (non logged user can see table with all events), but after a user logon (Session["Level"] is changed to 1 or 0 on mvc controller), DIV is not refreshed. I do not see additional column.

Does anybody has an idea how to resolve this ? I do not want to create 2 DIVs for the same thing ...

Comment: It's not clear to me how you expect the div to refresh.

Comment: Also which div? Both code snippets contain no div, nor an ng-repeat

Comment: I have added whole DIV, which has to be refreshed ... after user is logged in.. and session is changed on mvc controller

Comment: The way you have it the div will never "refresh" unless you do a postback and reload the page. This is because the `session` information is only known to the server and that part of the html is built up server side. So any async (ajax) style action using `$http` (for something like login) would not cause that to "refresh". Also using `HttpContext.Current.Session["Level"]` is just a bad idea, ideally MVC should be stateless.